# How can I use Like operator in mssql(node.js)

Tags: sql-server, node.js, azure

I'm using mssql(node.js).
I want to execute SQL having LIKE.

But I can't find out in below page
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#input-name-type-value

my code is this.But it doesn't work(result is 0 record)

```
mssql.connect(config, function(err) {

var request = new mssql.Request();
request.input('name',mssql.NVarChar,name);

request.query("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE name LIKE '%@name%',function(err,data){
//
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try representing the entire `LIKE` expression with a parameter, and then bind it using a concatenation, e.g.

```
var name = 'Yoshihide Nishimoto';

request.query("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE name LIKE ?", '%' + name + '%',
    function(err, data) {
        // code here
    }
)
```

Comment: Thank you!! It become working by changing the code to request.input('name',mssql.NVarChar,'%' + name + '%');

Answer (score 1):

You can use prepared statement like `"select * from t where '%' + @param + '%'"`.

For example:

```
mssql.connect(config, function(err) {

var request = new mssql.Request();
request.input('name', mssql.NVarChar,name);

request.query("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE name LIKE '%' + @name + '%'", function(err,data){
//
}
```